# using Jquery to return distinct value in row of dropdowns

Tags: jquery, html

I have a row of check boxes with drop downs associated with them. How can I return the value in the corresponding dropdown for the checkbox that is selected?

http://jsfiddle.net/Gqzhq/21/

```
$('input[name=options]').live('click', function() {

    if($(this).hasClass('checked'))
    {
    $(this).removeClass('checked');

    }else{
    $(this).addClass('checked');

    }

    });
```

---

HTML

```
<table id="test" summary="test">
<th>A</th> <th>B</th><th>C</th>

<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="options" id="1" value="500">
      <select class="my_select">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="options" id="2" value="500">
    <select class="my_select">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option></td>

    <td><input type="checkbox" name="options" id="3" value="500">
    <select class="my_select">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option></td>

    </tr>

    </table>
```

Comment: You are missing closing `</select>` tags.. and `ID`'s shouldn't start with a number.  You should also wrap your `TH`'s with `<thead>` and your table body with `<tbody>`

Answer (score 2):

You can target the select using `siblings()` or go up to the parent `TD` and use `find()`. Also `live()` is deprecated, use `on()` instead.

if you use `toggleClass()` you can remove your `if($(this).hasClass('checked'))`

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[name=options]', function() {){
    /* "this" within the handler refers to current input*/

   var selectVal= $(this).siblings('select').val();
             /* OR */
   var selectVal= $(this).parent().find('select').val();

   /* second argument determines  whether to add or remove*/ 
   $(this).toggleClass('checked', this.checked);

});
```

API References:

http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    if($(this).attr('checked')) 
        alert(
                'value of combo ' + 
                 $(this).attr('id') + ' is ' + 
                 $(this).next('.my_select').val()
             );
});
```

I changed your example http://jsfiddle.net/Gqzhq/27/

Comment: should use `prop()` method for `checked` in jQuery versions 1.6 and higher